# proof of perpendicular lines in a circle

Tags: geometry

$AB$ is a chord of a circle, centre $O$, and $M$ is its midpoint . The radius from $O$ is drawn through the midpoint $M$. Prove that $OM$ is perpendicular to $AB$.

I know that the product of perpendicular lines is $(-1)$ but i dont know how to express this problem as a proof.

Comment: http://everythingmaths.co.za/grade-11/08-euclidean-geometry/08-euclidean-geometry-02.cnxmlplus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Lets focus on triangles MOA and MOB**

- OA = OB because O is center of circle and A and B are on the circle
- AM = BM since M is midpoint of AB
- Triangles MOA and MOB have MO in common
- Therefore triangles MOA and MOB have same sides and same angles but are mirrored along OM.
- This implies Angle OMA = Angle OMB .
- Also these two angles are supplementary since OM falls on AB

Equal supplementary angles are right angles: Angles OMA and OMB are right angles[image: Illustration of points and circle]

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Look at the triangle $\;\Delta AOB\;$ and observe this is an isosceles triangle (why?) with basis $\;AB\;$.

But then $\;OM\;$ is the median to the basis in an isosceles triangle, thus...

BTW, you *also* have that $\;\angle AOM=\angle BOM\;$ ...

Answer (score 0):

Notice $OA = OB = r $, where $r$ is the radius of circle. Since $AM = MB$ by hypothesis, $\Delta AMO \cong \Delta BMO$. Also, we have $\angle AOM = \angle  BOM = \gamma $. Similarly, $\angle MAO = \angle MBO = \beta $. We want to show that $\angle BMO = \alpha = 90^o$. Well, since sum of angles in a triangle is $180$, then

$$ 2\gamma + 2 \beta = 180 \implies \gamma + \beta = 90 $$

Since $\alpha + \gamma + \alpha = 180$, then

$\alpha = 90 $ as desired.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: in $∆OAM$ and $∆OBM$,

$AM=BM$ [∴M is the midpoint of AB]

$AO=BO$ [∴Radius of the same circle]

$M=M$   [Common line]

Therefore, $∆OAM≡∆OBM$ [SSS Theorem]
∴ $∠OMA=∠OMB$

Step 2: Since the two angles together make a straight angle and are equal.
Therefore, $OMA=OMB=1$ right angle
$∴ OM⊥AB$
[Proved.]